# Enable specific debug-flag in gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to enable debug-flag (VtoPhys) in gem5.(because I need to trace the VtoPhys address mapping in gem5/src/arch/x86/vtophys.cc)

So I am running the command as below-

**build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=VtoPhys configs/example/fs.py --disk-image="path to my disk image**"

But it is not giving any output on the terminal about the address conversion.What am I missing here??

Comment: Can you just confirm that those debug prints are actually getting hit? E.g. put `cout <<` or GDB step debug.

Comment: Oh yes,I think It is not hitting the code. I want to get the virtual to physical memory mapping .As per my understanding, For SE Mode -> gem5 uses gem5/src/mem/page_table.cc file for virtual to physical address conversion.I checked in page_table.cc that MMU debug-flag is used in page_table.cc. On enabling this flag, I am able to get the address mapping on the terminal.

Comment: But for FS mode, as per my understanding , it uses gem5/src/arch/x86/vtophys.cc .I tried enabling VtoPhys flag but its not showing the memory conversion. memory mapping from virtual to physical  not  happening from this file? If not, Pls help me figure out the correct file.  Note: I am using x86 architecture.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know much about this part. Try reading the source further, step debug it, and ask on mailing list if you are still stuck ;-)